# How to disable appbar on splashscreen

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi how do i disable appbar from loading during splash screen flutter? I tried adding it into scaffold only but still the same.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:double_back_to_close_app/double_back_to_close_app.dart';
import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';

Future main() async {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String _outputText = "";
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initOneSignal();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: IndexedStack(
      index: 0,
      children: <Widget>[
        InAppWebViewPage(),
        Container(
          child: Text(_outputText),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }

  Future<void> initOneSignal() async {
    await OneSignal.shared
        .init("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", iOSSettings: null);
    OneSignal.shared
        .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);
    OneSignal.shared
        .setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
      this.setState(() {
        _outputText =
            "Received notification: \n${notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll("\\n", "\n")}";
      });
    });
  }
}

class InAppWebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InAppWebViewPageState createState() => new _InAppWebViewPageState();
}

class _InAppWebViewPageState extends State<InAppWebViewPage> {
  InAppWebViewController webView;
  int _page = 2;
  bool _loadError = false;
  StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> subscription;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    subscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      if (result != ConnectivityResult.none && webView != null) {
        print("reload");
        _loadError = false;
        webView.reload();
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    subscription.cancel();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _page,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: InAppWebView(
              initialUrl: "www.google.com",
              initialHeaders: {},
              initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
                crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                  userAgent: Platform.isIOS
                      ? 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15' +
                          ' (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1'
                      : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) ' +
                          'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Mobile Safari/537.36',
                  clearCache: false,
                  debuggingEnabled: true,
                ),
              ),
              onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
                webView = controller;
              },
              onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
              onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {
                print(url);
                setState(() {
                  if (!_loadError) {
                    _page = 0;
                  } else {
                    _page = 1;
                  }
                });
              },
              onLoadError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                  int code, String message) async {
                print("error $url: $code, $message");
                _loadError = true;
              },
              onLoadHttpError: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url,
                  int statusCode, String description) async {
                print("HTTP error $url: $statusCode, $description");
              },
            ),
          ),
          (Platform.isAndroid)
              ? Container(
                  child: Text("My custom error message"),
                )
              : Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/splash.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                )),
          Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: ExactAssetImage('assets/images/splash.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I already tried searching for a few answer but i cant seem to find the one related to flutter. Do you guys know where should i put the appbar so it wont show on splash screen? Thank in advance!

Below is my pubspec.yaml as requested :

```
name: testing_app
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: "none" # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+2

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_inappwebview: ^3.4.0
  connectivity: ^2.0.2
  double_back_to_close_app: ^2.0.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^2.0.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.8.0"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
```

Comment: There is no appBar in your code ?

Comment: I removed it, because same problem as i mention above. so not sure where to put it

Comment: Please also share the dependencies versions from pubsec.yaml to help recreate this issue.

Comment: ok will share it to you